# UISlider background disappears

Tags: objective-c, uislider

I use UISlider for video player to track and change the location of the playback.

It seems that when ever I change the slider.value from code, the background line of the slider disappears.

It changes from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

(I added the gray background color)

What can cause this issue?

Comment: Does this question hold a clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317366/ios-iphone-uislider-track-image-disappearing-randomly

Comment: Yes it did. I tried the setValue, but what really helped was checking value to NaN - Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

As trojanfoe suggested, I looked at this question:

[iOS - iPhone : UISlider track image disappearing randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317366/ios-iphone-uislider-track-image-disappearing-randomly)

In simple words: I used `[UISlider setValue:animated:]` and made sure I don't get `NaN`, which was the real problem.